# Efficiency of std::sort() algorithm in sorting std::vector of std::list

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, smart-pointers

The example below is adopted from Jossuttis(2012), with some small changes.

Essentially, it's sorting a vector of lists of integers.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is the `std::sort()` algorithm sorting the pointers (to the lists)?
2. If the answer is no, what's the best way to still use `std::sort()` to sort a vector of (smart) pointers to containers?

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>

inline void INSERT_ELEMENT(T& coll, int first, int last){
    for(int i=first; i<=last; ++i)
        coll.insert(coll.end(), i);
}

template<typename T>

inline void PRINT_ELEMENTS(const T& coll, const std::string& optcstr=""){
    std::cout << optcstr;
    for(auto elem:coll)
        std::cout << elem << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(){

    list<int> c1, c2, c3, c4;
    INSERT_ELEMENT(c1, 1, 5);
    c2 = c3 = c4 = c1;

    c1.push_back(7);
    c3.push_back(2);
    c3.push_back(0);
    c4.push_back(2);

    vector<list<int>> cc{ c1, c2, c3, c4, c3, c1, c4, c2};

    for(auto elem: cc){
        PRINT_ELEMENTS(elem);
    }
    cout << endl;

    sort(
        cc.begin(), 
        cc.end(), 
        [](const list<int>& first, const list<int>& second){
            return lexicographical_compare(
                first.cbegin(), 
                first.cend(),
                second.cbegin(),
                second.cend()
            );
        }
    );
    for(auto elem: cc){
        PRINT_ELEMENTS(elem);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the usage of any pointers here. What led you to believe that pointers are involved? And what does "the best way" mean?

Comment: running the code should anser your question, no?

Comment: What is your sorting criteria?

Comment: When you sort an array/vector of objects using comparison sorts, you could swap the objects when they are out of order or swap the pointers to the objects. If the objects are large, you want the latter approach. In my example, the lists are tiny, but if they were huge, what would be the best way to minimize moving around big objects in memory? By best way I mean, using pointers that could free all memory they are pointing to upon destruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is the std::sort() algorithm sorting the pointers (to the lists)?*

No, neither in c++11 or c++03. The difference is the since c++11, move semantic is used in sorting.

I think what you are actually asked is about [move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) semantic. For `std::list`, they are moveable, and in the implementation of `std::sort`, the element swap is based on the move in c++11. So since c++11, the sort of `std::vector<std::list<T>>` is cheap. If you have pre c++11, then we may consider use pointers to make the swap(based on copy) cheap: `std::vector<std::list<T>*>` to make the sort faster, and it's recommended to upgrade the old compiler to get a performance boost.

You can verify it by change your code to print the elements address, they are not changed after sorting, then we confirmed that the list is moved but not copyied, your original code have uncesssary copy in range for loop, I have fixed it:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>

inline void INSERT_ELEMENT(T& coll, int first, int last) {
  for (int i = first; i <= last; ++i) coll.insert(coll.end(), i);
}

template <typename T>

inline void PRINT_ELEMENTS(const T& coll, const std::string& optcstr = "") {
  std::cout << optcstr;
  for (auto& elem : coll) std::cout << &elem << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  list<int> c1, c2, c3, c4;
  INSERT_ELEMENT(c1, 1, 5);
  c2 = c3 = c4 = c1;

  c1.push_back(7);
  c3.push_back(2);
  c3.push_back(0);
  c4.push_back(2);

  vector<list<int>> cc{c1, c2, c3, c4, c3, c1, c4, c2};

  for (auto& elem : cc) {
    PRINT_ELEMENTS(elem);
  }
  cout << endl;

  sort(cc.begin(), cc.end(),
       [](const list<int>& first, const list<int>& second) {
         return lexicographical_compare(first.cbegin(), first.cend(),
                                        second.cbegin(), second.cend());
       });
  for (auto& elem : cc) {
    PRINT_ELEMENTS(elem);
  }
}
```

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3r1b74Ys4)

Comment: Thanks @prehistoricpenguin Your explanation is very helpful
I also found the following resources to be helpful in understanding the move semantic
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics/11540204#11540204
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom

Comment: @bst0612 Yes, these answers are great!